# Large MVC controller for a web-based "Wizard" - what are some ways I could reduce size and redundancy?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a very large (77 actions) controller that I am using to make a site with wizard-like functionality. The site is like a "job application manager" with multiple components such as an admin component and an end-user component. The component I'm working with is the part where the user would actually fill out a job application. The way things are structured with the other components, it makes the most sense to put all of the job application stuff in the same controller. All of these actions perform similar things but on different models, like so:

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Action1() 
    {
        Guid appId = new Guid(Session["AppId"].ToString());
        ... // logic to pull up correct model
        return View(model)
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Action1(FormCollection formValues)
    {
        Guid appId = new Guid(Session["AppId"].ToString());
        ... // logic to update the model
        return RedirectToAction("Action2");
    }

    public ActionResult Action2()
    {
        Guid appId = new Guid(Session["AppId"].ToString());
        ... // logic to pull up the correct model
        return View(model)
    }

    ... // on and on and on for 74 more actions
}
```

Is there any way to reduce some of the constant redundancy that's in every one of the actions? Here is what I am thinking:

- Creating a member variable Guid to store the appId and then overriding OnActionExecuting to populate this variable. Is this a good idea?
- Implementing some kind of paging to cut down on the number of actions. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say yes to your first point and "it depends" to your second. Don't change your design just because you have a lot of methods, if all 77 `ActionResult` methods make sense to have, then keep them around.

Using a member variable and overriding `OnActionExecuting` seems like a great way to refactor that appID Guid code into a single place, so you can **quickly** and **easily** modify it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Normally for wizard view, a single action and page is used with multiple divs which can be shown according to the steps.

For example, a registration wizard screen having 4 steps, can be be handled in a single page with divs for each steps. You can make use of JavaScript and css to make it a wizard flow.

Make use of ajax to update different models, if necessary in between the steps.

Comment: I've used this approach for smaller wizard-like sites, but that's not a good idea for one with 70 different pages. That would take forever to load.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to put your logic (Job Manager related) in a single repository/manager class. Different controllers associated with different views(e.g AdminController, EndUserController etc) can call methods from same repository/manager class.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be replacing this..

```
Guid appId = new Guid(Session["AppId"].ToString());
```

..with a call to something like the following:

```
private Guid GetAppId(){
    return new Guid(Session["AppId"].ToString());
}
```

Now you could just use `GetAppId()` instead wherever you currently use `appId`. You could of course cache the GUID in the form of a class variable, as you suggest, but it might be a good idea to limit the access and use of that variable to a method like this (get it's value via the method). Might be a little more flexible in case you want to change something later.

As for dividing the page into several pages; sure, go ahead, if it makes sense and feels right. Over 70 actions in one class does sound like a lot. If it makes more sense to keep them there however, you could try to move as much logic as possible out from the methods themselves, and into helper-classes instead. I always try to keep the actions as small as possible, and put the logic in separate classes, each of which is tailored to do one specific thing.

My point is, if each action is no more than 2-4 lines, then 70+ actions is not necessarily a problem.

Comment: I did at one point try to use a GetAppId() method as you suggested but because I use the appId variable with LINQ expressions it does not work.